# Adding dividing lines into a asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net (vb) `gridview` containing a list of items including dates and times. I would like to insert a dividing line (or thin row) between items so that it divides the list by day. Something like:

```
¦Monday 22-Jul ¦ Item One    ¦
¦Monday 22-Jul ¦ Item Two    ¦
------------------------------
¦Tuesday 23-Jul¦ Item Three  ¦ 
¦Tuesday 23-Jul¦ Item Four   ¦
¦Tuesday 23-Jul¦ Item Five   ¦
```

I'm guessing that the answer will be to not use `gridview`, but any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: It's been a while since I used gridview and webforms but I'm pretty sure there's a 'onrowdatabinding' event you can hook into - then just apply a css class if the row fits the criteria

Comment: You can define a new List, after that make a foreach loop with the ordered old list. Check if the date is different from the previous date. If it is the same, just add the current Item to the new list, if it is not the same, add first a dividor item and then add the current item. After the loop, bind the new list to the gridview.

Comment: Search here for `empty row in gridview` and similar.